# A Facebook Chat Bot now possible with XMPP?

Tags: facebook, xmpp

With Facebook now supporting XMPP, would it be possible to implement a simple chat bot, perhaps through an app (i.e. conversations not coming from an individual).

Answer (score 2):

Probably late, but yes writing xmpp bot for facebook is now possible using any xmpp library. Jaxl library written in PHP is one option for you, it do also support X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM authentication http://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You will need a Facebook account to authenticate as. I am not sure about s2s offhand but a c2s bot is possible.